# Prestashop add to cart is not working

Tags: web, e-commerce, prestashop, web-deployment, prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop for my e-commerce website. When I click on a product item, my browser console shows the error below. Also when I click on the `add to cart` button, it is showing "there are no more items in your cart".

[image]

Comment: Does this error appear when the page is loaded, before adding product to the cart?